# Custom loss function for sequential output in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I need to write a custom loss for my keras model. As I need to write the function using Keras functions for auto-backpropagation, I am not sure how I will implement this, as this might require some looping operations -

```
Target[1*300] - [...0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0...]

Output[1*300] - [...0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0...]
```

What I need is that while calculating loss I don't need a exact match.
Even if my output has a discrepancy of +/- *three* places. I want it to mark it to consider this as a correct prediction.

For example, both of these should be considered as the right predictions -

```
Output[1*300] - [...0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0...]

Output[1*300] - [...0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0...]
```

The code which I have written till now -

```
import tensorflow as tf
tar = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 10))
tar_unpacked = tf.unstack(tar) 

pred = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 10))
pred_unpacked = tf.unstack(pred) 


for t in tar_unpacked:
    result_tensor = tf.equal(t,1)

tar_ind = tf.where(result_tensor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([tar_ind], feed_dict={tar:np.asarray([[0, 0,1, 0,0,0,1,0,0,0]]),pred:np.asarray([[0, 0,1, 0,0,0,1,0,0,0]])}))
```

Now what I want to do next is generate valid indexes by adding each from

```
[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]
```

to elements in `tar_ind` and then compare the indexes with `pred_unstacked`.

My naive loss would be `1 - (NUM_MATCHED/TOTAL)`

But the problem is that `tar_ind` is a variably sized tensor, and I cannot loop over it for the next operation.

**Update-1.**

As suggested by @user36624, I tried the alternate approach of having `tf.py_func` which gives the updated `y_pred` and then I used the updated ones for `binary cross-entropy.`

As I have implemented the function using `py_func,` It is giving me error as `ValueError: An operation has`None`for the gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e., are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.`

Also as he suggested that I need to manually stop gradients which I don't know how to do?

```
def specificity_loss_wrapper():
    def specificity_loss(y_true, y_pred):

        y_pred = tf.py_func(best_match,[y_true,y_pred],(tf.float32))

        y_pred = tf.stop_gradient(y_pred)
        y_pred.set_shape(y_true.get_shape())


        return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

    return specificity_loss    

spec_loss = specificity_loss_wrapper()
```

and

```
...
model.compile(loss=spec_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
...
```

In my understanding, `binary_crossentropy` should be differentiable.

Thanks

Comment: Would you elaborate more on "discrepancy of +/- three places"? How do you define the discrepancy? And specify the labels shape as well, i.e. each label is an array of shape `(300,)` so the labels array would have a shape of `(n_samples, 300)`? Further, do the labels consist of only zeros and ones?

Comment: I have time-series data, and each slot is for some `N` minutes in some order, so even if my predictions are `+/- 30 minutes`, I would be fine with the results. The shape of a label is as `(1,300)`, i.e. `(num_samples,300)` for all inputs. In my example code, I have taken it as `10`, but that is just for testing purposes.

Comment: Please be more specific and provide examples if you can. What is the "+/- 30 minutes"? Is it equivalent to one step in the 300 steps? I can't understand the exact definition of discrepancy yet: for example if the k-th element of target is 1 then any prediction with a 1 in either k-3, k-2, k-1, ..., k+3 places is acceptable?? And what if there is no 1 in that places? What is the value of loss? When you want to implement a loss function you must first be able to define it mathematically on a paper at least.

Comment: Using `py_func` to compute the loss will not give you the gradient for sure. This is nothing related to the error message that you saw `ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.`

Comment: What I suggested you is to modify `y_true` instead of `y_pred`. These two things seem to be equivalent, but they are not. Given `y_pred_mod=f(y_pred)`, and `loss=g(y_pred_mod, y_true)`, then both functions `f` and `g` have to be differentiable to compute loss gradients w.r.t. `y_pred`. In contrast, given `y_true_mod=f(y_true)` and `loss=g(y_pred, y_true_mod)`, only function `g` needs to be differentiable to compute loss gradients w.r.t. `y_pred`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is to compute

```
1. offsets = compute_index_offsets( y_true, y_pred )
2. loss = 1 - num(offsets <= 3)/total
```

I suggest to solve it in an alternative way.

```
1. y_true_mod = DP_best_match( y_true, y_pred )
2. loss = 1 - num(y_true_mod==y_pred)/total
```

The advantage of modifying `y_true` is that it is equivalent to providing a new target value, and thus it is not a part of the model graph optimization or the loss computation.

What  `DP_best_match( y_true, y_pred )` should do is to modify `y_true` according to `y_pred`,

e.g. given

```
y_true[1*300]     - [...0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0...]
y_pred[1*300]     - [...0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0...]
```

then `DP_best_match( y_true, y_pred )` should give the new target

```
y_true_mod[1*300] - [...0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0...]
```

Note, `DP_best_match( y_true, y_pred )` is aiming to modify `y_true` to best match `y_pred`, so it is deterministic and nothing to optimize. Thus, no need to have backpropagation. This means you need to **manually stop gradients** if you implement `DP_best_match( y_true, y_pred )` in `tf`. Otherwise, you can implement it in numpy and wrap the function via `tf.py_func`, which might be easier to implement.

Final remark, you should make sure the proposed loss function makes sense. For me, it makes more sense to use `binary_crossentropy` or `mse` after finding the best `y_true_mod`.

Comment: Hey, I intended to modify the loss after I was done with the matching part. I know subtracting one, does not make sense. Let me try the `tf.py_func`.